# A tricky converged VoIP design

Tags: networking, routing, vlan, voip, network-design

A client (roughly 30 people) wants to replace their existing analog phone system with VoIP. However:

- they have dual Ethernet drops to some desks, but not all
- their (recently purchased) router does not support 802.1Q VLANs
- their (recently purchased) core switch is layer 2 only

Is there any viable, reasonable solution that would allow them to:

- avoid replacing router or switch
- avoid running new Ethernet drops

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Decent VOIP phones?

Starts with that:

- A decent VOIP phone has a passtrhough switch. Come in on the phone, go out to the computer. The phone also gets powered by Ethernet - which is the point throwing the stupid switches they bought out and tell the uy that bought them he should take a job at McDonalds serving burgers.
- Alternatively buy cheap small desktop switch is always an option.
- 802.1Q VLANs is not really needed at all, you know, unless it is needed for other reasons, but nothing DEMANDS voip traffic to be on a VLAN.

Comment: Power over ethernet surely? Or if you where to get electricity via IPv4 can you point to me a server? ;)

Comment: Ethernet, yes ;) Ipv4 - sure. I heary your computer can pull a lot from 127.0.0.1 ;) Just make sure that server is on first ;)

Comment: Most of those phones also allow you to buy power bricks as well so you don't have to use PoE

Comment: +1 for 802.1q, best 'fix' it up now, rather then messing with it in the future if demands increases with QOS.

Comment: Actually you can do QOS without VLAN. VLAN is more a security issue - but that is really not needed in most companies. If you now your way around windows (and the phones) you can set DCP priorities easily wihtout ever using a VLAN. Plus 1gbit is a lot - I would say for a smaller install, the overhead in administration even for QOS is most likely not needed. People doing phone calls a lot normally are not the people copying gigabytes to their machine ;) From a practical point.

Comment: @TomTom: Vlans are not needed on the router, but needed on the switch to use only 1 cable per desk.

Comment: Again: NO. I run that exactly like that on ONE network, NO VLAN. Point. Heck, we even have a switch in the VOIP phones, 2 ports - one up, one to the computer. No Vlans. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

two unusual options:

- softphones - they actually work
- dect phones with voip-aware base station like solutions from [ascom](http://www.ascom.com/en/productsheet_ascom_ip-dect_access_point_print.pdf) or [gigaset](http://gigaset.com/pro/hq/en/product/GIGASETN720DECTIPPRO.html).

Comment: devt? I assume you mean dect: digital cordless

Comment: indeed - i meant dect. typo fixed.